# How do I fix weather-info not showing

Tags: javascript, weather-api

I've been trying to add weather-info to my website using api but cant get it to work, don't really know what the problem is. The temperature of a preset location, which is all i need to display, just doesn't show up.

I tried getting elementByID from a div in my HTML-code but this didnt work so now I'm using a table and trying to insert it into the table.

```
function addWeather(JSONdata) {
    /* let temperatureNow = document.getElementById("temp");*/
    let table1 = document.getElementById("table");
    let rowNr = 1;

    let today = new Date();
    let time = today.getHours();

    for (let i = 0; i < JSONdata.length; i++) {
        let tempDate = new Date(JSONdata.timeSeries[i].validTime);
        let hoursTemp = tempDate.getHours();

        let row = table1.insertRow(rowNr);
        let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);

        if (time == hoursTemp
        ) {
            /*temperatureNow == JSONdata.timeSeries[i].parameters[1].values[0];*/
            for (let index = 0; index < JSONdata.timeSeries[i].parameters.length; index++) {
                if (JSONdata.timeSeries[i].parameters[index].name == "t") {
                    console.log(JSONdata.timeSeries[i])
                    cell1.innerHTML = JSONdata.timeSeries[i].parameters[index].values + '&#8451;';

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit as to what you are asking and what currently happens with your code?

Comment: can you console.log(JSONdata) at the beginning and add the value to the example? and also, can you add the html?